# Plotting a function based on complicated integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have this function :

```
f[Lambda_] := K Integrate[x Exp[- x^2-Lambda x]
HypergeometricU[-Lambda,1/2,(x+ Lambda/2+2)^2],{x,0,Infinity}];
```

where

```
K = 1/(Lambda (Lambda +4)/(4(4-Lambda)) 
    HypergeometricU[1 -Lambda,3/2, ( Lambda+ 4)^2/4] + 
    Integrate[Exp[-y /2( 2 y +2 Lambda)] 
    HypergeometricU[- Lambda,1/2,(2y Lambda+4)^2/4],{y,0,Infinity}])
```

I want to plot it for `lambda` in $[0,4]$, but it seems that it is too complicated to plot directly. I wanted to know what is the best way to have an approximated plot of this function.

Comment: Have you actually tried to plot it and something has not worked? Show what you have tried and the error you are receiving. While you are editing your post format your code with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the definitions in the original question were problematic. I edited the question to have more consistent code.

In order to plot the function numerical values are needed, so using `Integrate` is not necessary. We can use `NIntegrate` instead. The plot is produced within 30 seconds on my laptop with Mathematica 10.3.1.

Here is the function redefined:

```
fn[Lambda_?NumericQ] :=
  Block[{K},
   K = 1/(Lambda (Lambda + 4)/(4 (4 - Lambda)) HypergeometricU[
         1 - Lambda, 3/2, (Lambda + 4)^2/4] + 
       NIntegrate[
        Exp[-y/2 (2 y + 2 Lambda)] HypergeometricU[-Lambda, 
          1/2, (2 y Lambda + 4)^2/4], {y, 0, Infinity}, 
        Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]); 
   K*NIntegrate[
     x Exp[-x^2 - Lambda x] HypergeometricU[-Lambda, 
       1/2, (x + Lambda/2 + 2)^2], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
   ];
```

Here is the plot of the function:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Plot[fn[x], {x, 0.1, 4}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am a beginner with Mathematica :D

Comment: @Rim No problem, good luck!